# Unused Dapper parameters are added to the query

Tags: sql-server, dapper

Unused Dapper parameters are added to the query.

If we took this example:

```
var parameters = new {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Age = 30,
    UnusedParameter = "This will not be used"
};

string query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName AND Age = @Age";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var result = connection.Query<User>(query, parameters);
    // Process result
}
```

Using SQL profiler, I noticed Dapper is using all the parameters in the query (included the `UnusedParameter`) in some cases, in others it uses only the parameters required from the query.

Update: Is giving me problems in the `DateTime` values who are not needed but still are in the query. In a dynamically generated SQL query, I give as parameters DateTimes to filter in case the frontend send it, in other case, the query doesn't include the line (example) "where DateFrom>@DateFrom", but the query is adding it as a `Datetime.MinValue` and the query doesn't work, sending the message:

> " SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM".

But I don't need the parameter in the query, so I don't understand why is on it, in other cases the parameter is not needed and is not included.

Any way to control this?

Comment: Why is it causing a problem? It doesn't matter if you pass extra parameters apart from a slight performance hit for the extra data?

Comment: "Is giving me problems in the DateTime values" - what problems? Can you give examples?

Comment: Dapper doesn't look at your query, it just sends everything. And `DateTime.MinValue` is not convertible as it's too low a value. Sounds like you should make that parameter nullable `DateTime? ConditionalParameter` then Dapper will pass it as `DBNull.Value`